# I try to use Grad-CAM on lib Keras but it error how can I solve it

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I try to create image classification model then I want to know the model are not cheating? by using Grad CAM
This is code Grad CAM from https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/

```
def make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, pred_index=None):
    # First, we create a model that maps the input image to the activations
    # of the last conv layer as well as the output predictions
    grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        [model.inputs], [model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output, model.output]
    )

    # Then, we compute the gradient of the top predicted class for our input image
    # with respect to the activations of the last conv layer
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(img_array)
        if pred_index is None:
            pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
        class_channel = preds[:, pred_index]

    # This is the gradient of the output neuron (top predicted or chosen)
    # with regard to the output feature map of the last conv layer
    grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)

    # This is a vector where each entry is the mean intensity of the gradient
    # over a specific feature map channel
    pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))

    # We multiply each channel in the feature map array
    # by "how important this channel is" with regard to the top predicted class
    # then sum all the channels to obtain the heatmap class activation
    last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_output[0]
    heatmap = last_conv_layer_output @ pooled_grads[..., tf.newaxis]
    heatmap = tf.squeeze(heatmap)

    # For visualization purpose, we will also normalize the heatmap between 0 & 1
    heatmap = tf.maximum(heatmap, 0) / tf.math.reduce_max(heatmap)
    return heatmap.numpy()
```

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Zph.png)

[This is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auOWW.png)

InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node _*wrapped__Mean_device*/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Invalid reduction dimension (2 for input with 2 dimension(s) [Op:Mean]

How can I fix it. Thank you

The solution that can fix my problem.